# Send Console.Error from user's mobile phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios, cordova

I would like to know if there is a way(tool) for sending error traces automatically from an user's mobile running a phonegap app.

I suppose that you could prepare a db table with a couple of fields in order to send log errors, but it would be great if there were an external API for doing so.

Thanks